# How to make autohotkey bind several send commands with only one key?

Tags: autohotkey

For example when I press #1 it sends `hey`

```
#1::
send hey
```

When I press `#1` again within 900 milliseconds I want it to send `hi` and so forth.

So what I want to achieve is to bind several commands by pressing the same button within a given time span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To chain key presses together as `N key presses per X milliseconds` you can use the following structure:

```
key::
    x = ;milliseconds

    if n > 0
    {
        n += 1
        return
    }

    n = 1
    SetTimer, Chain, %x%
    return

    Chain:
        SetTimer, Chain, off

        if n = 1
        {
            ;if key was pressed 1x
        }
        else if n = 2
        {
            ;if key was pressed 2x
        }
        else if n > 2
        {
            ;if key was pressed 3x or more
        }

    n = 0
    return
```

---

So, based on your example, we have:

```
#1::
    x = 900

    if n > 0
    {
        n += 1
        return
    }

    n = 1
    SetTimer, Chain, %x%
    return

    Chain:
        SetTimer, Chain, off

        if n = 1
        {
            Send, hey
        }
        else if n = 2
        {
            Send, hi
        }

    n = 0
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just use the `Sleep` command and pass milliseconds to it.

```
#1::
Send hey
Sleep, 900 ; 1 second
Send hi
return
```

For your last sentence, use a global variable and an if expression. So, instead of "Send hey" you would have an if where you select which string you send. Then you set a global variable to 1 after which you sleep, after sleeping you set it back to 0...

**See also:** [If](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm), [Hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm), [Sleep](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sleep.htm) and [Variables](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. My Question has been answered though. I just started with scripting and glad about your help